# Generation of jacoco.exec using bazel not permitted in other paths except /tmp

Tags: jacoco, bazel

In my BUILD.bazel my java_test looks like this:

```
java_test(
    name = "SomeServiceTest",
    srcs = [
      "src/test/java/com/service/SomeServiceTest.java",
    ],
    test_class = "com.service.SomeServiceTest",
    deps = [
        "SomeService",
        "@junit_junit//jar",
        "@commons_logging_commons_logging//jar",
        "@org_hamcrest_hamcrest_core//jar",
        "@com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_annotations//jar",
        "@javax_servlet_javax_servlet_api//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_aop//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_beans//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_context//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_test//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_web//jar",
        "@org_mockito_mockito_core//jar",
        "@net_bytebuddy_byte_buddy//jar",
    ],

    size = "medium",
    jvm_flags = ["-javaagent:$$workspacepath/jacocoagent-runtime.jar=destfile=$$workspacepath/jacoco.exec"]
)
```

I want to make the path of jacocoagent-runtime.jar and the path where the jacoco.exec will be generated to be dynamic, thus, the jvm_flags setup. I defined $$workspacepath in my execution of bazel test below:

```
bazel test --test_output=all --action_env=workspacepath=/Users/Someone/Desktop some-service:all_tests
```

Now, I am getting the error below:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Someone/Desktop/jacoco.exec (Operation not permitted)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_290345e.output.FileOutput.openFile(FileOutput.java:67)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_290345e.output.FileOutput.writeExecutionData(FileOutput.java:53)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_290345e.Agent.shutdown(Agent.java:137)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_290345e.Agent$1.run(Agent.java:54)
```

If I change the workspacepath to /tmp, it works fine. What is wrong with other paths other than /tmp?

Comment: Wild guess: sandboxing in Bazel - https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#sandboxing https://blog.bazel.build/2015/09/11/sandboxing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [@Godin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244993/godin) -- sounds like the input path is not in the sandbox. Does [`--spawn_strategy=standalone`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--spawn_strategy)[1] help?

If that's indeed the problem then to fix the build with sandboxing you need to make the .jar file an input of the `java_test`'s action and reference its path correctly from the `jvm_flags`.

To do that:

1. either create a new package in your workspace and copy the jacoco jar there, or add a `new_local_repository` rule to your `WORKSPACE` file and reference the jar's directory and specify the `build_file_contents` attribute as `exports_files(["jacoco-runtime.jar"])`
2. now that you can reference Jacoco by a label (e.g. `@jacoco//:jacoco-runtime.jar`) you need to add it to the `java_test` rule's `data` attribute
3. finally you need to change the `java_test` rule's `jvm_flags` attribute to reference the jar using `$(location <label>)`, e.g. `$(location @jacoco//:jacoco-runtime.jar)`

---

[1] https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--spawn_strategy

Comment: What I was trying to do was setting runtime jar's path different from the path where the jacoco.exec will be generated. I have been trying to add --spawn_strategy and --genrule_strategy to my commands but also to no avail. Your answer gave me the idea to have the paths the same (aside from inside /tmp) and voila! Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested to see a full example. Any chance you can post one on GitHub?